How do I read Next.js cookie from form action in middleware
I'm currently implementing basic JWT authentication within Next 14 and is currently working on protected routes.
This is the login logic in /login/action.ts
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function login(
  _: FormState,
  formData: FormData,
): Promise<FormState> {
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

  if (!data?.email || !data?.password) {
    // handle bad request
  }

  try {
    // ....
    // get data from db

    const token = await createJWT()

    cookies().set("session", token, {
      expires: Date.now() + 3600 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
      path: "/",
      secure: true,
    });

    console.log(cookies().get("token")); // this cookie existed!
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
  }

  return { type: "success" };
}


As you can see, there's nothing wrong with this form action and cookies has been successfully set using next/header's cookies.
In the middleware file however, this cookie became undefined
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const jwt = cookies().get("token")?.value;

  console.log({ jwt }); // this is undefined

  return NextResponse.next({
    ...
  });
}

I found similar question but I wonder if there's any update on it. Thank you in advance!

try with 'jwt = request.cookies.get("session")' instead of 'cookies().get("token")' I don't know if cookies() is available in Middlewares, but if it is, it would be better to use the actual name of the cookie

You can access the cookies from NextRequest.
Try to log the request value you pass to the middleware.
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("Cookies:", request.cookies);

...remaining code....
}

